# Взять средние разряды

Tags: matlab

Как в matlab взять средние разряды числа ?

Допустим, есть число 0.04247786 и как мне из него сделать 0.2477 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 0.04247786
y = num2str(a,10)

out = str2double([num2str(fix(a)),'.',y(find(y=='.')+3:end)])
```